# Rabl return string Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

In my controller I have

```
app_key = Application.find_by_name(params[:id].capitalize).app_key
@response = app_key == params[:app_key] ? "200" : "403"
```

I would like to return response :

"response" => @response , how to do it using Rabl in Rails??

Answer (score 0):

Use `render :file => 'your_view', :status => @response` inside your controller action (and in respond_to block, if you have one). I think the status should be a number, not string.